# Creating Domain Model mapper with complex DTO

Tags: android, domain-driven-design, dto, clean-architecture, domain-model

I am using JSON to Kotlin plugin for generating DTO classes with Moshi to save a lot of time dealing with complex JSON response from APIs.

Just to give a glimpse how huge the response can be

[image]

Sample DTO using Moshi

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class AssetDto(
    @Json(name = "data")
    val `data`: List<AssetData> = listOf(),
    @Json(name = "status")
    val status: Status = Status()
)

@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Status(
    @Json(name = "elapsed")
    val elapsed: Int = 0,
    @Json(name = "timestamp")
    val timestamp: String = ""
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class AssetData(
    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: String = "",
    @Json(name = "metrics")
    val metrics: Metrics = Metrics(),
    @Json(name = "name")
    val name: String = "",
    @Json(name = "profile")
    val profile: Profile = Profile(),
    @Json(name = "symbol")
    val symbol: String? = ""
) : Parcelable
```

**Problems**

1. I want to know what is the best way to create Domain Model out of a complex DTO class without manually encoding it.
2. Should I create Domain Model for `AssetDto` or `AssetData`? As you can see I have tons of value-object and I do not know if I should create a Domain Model on each of those value-object or it is okay to reuse the data class from DTO.

For now I generate another pile of plain data class using JSON to Kotlin which means I have dozens of identical data class and it looks like I am still oblige to manually set each values, this became a total blocker now. I am not sure if I should continue implementing mapper.

```
data class AssetDomain(
    var status: Status? = Status(),
    var `data`: List<Data>? = listOf()
)

data class Status(
    var elapsed: Int? = 0,
    var timestamp: String? = ""
)

data class Data(
    var id: String? = "",
    var metrics: Metrics? = Metrics(),
    var name: String? = "",
    var profile: Profile? = Profile(),
    var symbol: String? = ""
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create domain models based on your business logic not based on the response itself.

Comment: Agree but still, if the domain model is too big the problem still exist. You have to map them manually. I already minimize the response data when mapping it to domain but it is still big/complex.

Comment: I have the same question like you. Anyone can help? Please

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @LongGiang unfortunately right now I don't, I guess doing it manually is the best option right now since you have full control in which data should be included in domain model coming from DTO.